# Do people add onions when cooking meat via sous vide

Tags: meat, sous-vide, onions

I never really see or hear of people adding onion to the bag when they are cooking meat with sous vide. Are there any reasons not to add onion? Would it affect the texture of the meat?

Comment: The "Chaliapin Steak" reputedly tenderizes meat, so there could well be some enzyme action going on by adding onions.

Comment: If you expect/want a "normal" onion with meat sort of flavor, you might want to use pre-carmelized onions rather than raw onions for this. I don't believe they will caramelize at SV temperatures as they do in a pan, so the flavor contribution would be quite different.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks for the suggestion. I'm gonna try adding carmelized onions to my venison roast cook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried @thrig's idea of making caramelized onions first and adding them to the bag and it worked wonderfully.

Answer (score -1):

I have made beautiful caramelised onions sous vide, but I fried them off in butter first to soften and reduce the gassiness (which apparently can make a vac sealed bag expand and potentially burst).  I added balsamic and honey, then SV'd for 5 hours at 85 degrees C.  They were to die for.

Comment: Adding balsamic and honey sounds much like "seasoned" rather than "caramelized" onions - when I make caramelized onions on the stovetop it's just a big pan full of onions which make their own sweetness and brown-ness with no need for outside seasonings...